# Name of a certain modern rear-derailleur part at upper end of pivot

Tags: parts, derailleur-rear

Some derailleurs, particularly "old style" drop-out-mounted ones have a pivot whose upper end is a kind of combination joint: it has a bushing that allows the pivot to rotate, under spring action, and that joint also has attachments for the pivot's parallelogram members.

Newer style direct-mount derailleurs (but even new drop-out-mount ones like the Shimano RD-TX55) elongate this upper joint of the pivot into a small member. The rotating bushing is on the upper end of this member (rotating around the mounting bolt on the DM units), and the parallelogram members attach at the lower end of this member.

**Does this member have a special name? Is it considered part of the pivot, or are only the parallelogram arms "the pivot"?**

**For that matter, does the original "combination joint" have a name, and is it considered separate from the pivot?**

Comment: A picture with the relevant part circled would help.

Comment: There are a zillion schematics of rear derailleurs on the web, can you maybe do a Google image search until you see one of the deralliurs you're trying to describe? I can see 2 issues right now that will make it difficult to help - the first is actually idenfying the part, as you're asking, but the second is identifying the derailleur.

Comment: As others have mentioned, this is very difficult to answer without pictures. For the moment, I am closing your question as "unclear what you are asking." If you upload a picture, your question will automatically be flagged for reopening.

Answer (score 3):

If it's the part I think you mean, [Shimano](http://si.shimano.com/php/download.php?file=pdf/ev/EV-RD-M8000-3859A.pdf) label it as either the Bracket Axel Unit or the B-Axel depending on if it's the direct mount or standard mount variant.